# NSPredicate: validating user input

Tags: cocoa, core-data, validation, nspredicate

I'm allowing a user to search data and show the results in a table view using Core Data. Apple recommends validating any user input passed to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]`, but I can't seem to find any examples or discussion of how to do this.

My first thought is to only escape "*" and "?" since I'm using substitution variables and I'm assuming the framework will escape any quotes since it adds the quotes around the substituted value.

Is this the best way to do this? Can anyone point to discussions or example code of securely validating user input in Cocoa?

Comment: Is this a simple search field, or something elaborate like an `NSPredicateEditor` view?  There is some information on validation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html

Comment: This is validation ala sql injection-type attacks, or if the user actually wants to search for a question mark or asterisk.